# Cannot login to cPanel with ftp account through web browser

Tags: cpanel

I have a "shared Hosting account" on GoDaddy which have hosted more than 3 domains on it.
I want some one else accesses one of my domains without having accessbto other domains or their information. 
well, i created an ftp account like this:

log In: username@primarydomain.com

password: mypassword

### directory to access: public_html/www.domain.com

When i go to www.domain.com/cpanel
It goes to cPanel Login and asking for username and password.
i enter the above log in and pass but says "The login is invalid.".
(i don't want use Filezilla or other stuffs like, just from browser).
Any one came across with or instruct me how to figure it out is appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access cPanel using FTP account. You can only access the contents via FTP using your created FTP user. You can only access cPanel using your default cPanel user and this will give full access of your cPanel account.

You can only give FTP access to other person.

Answer (score 0):

1)while adding the FTP accounts , the directory path should be set to public_html

2) If you are looking for browser based FTP you can do it by Internet Explorer by enabling compatible FTP view in IE , drag and drop to upload and download file should work

3) The recommended way to use FTP is by using any FTP client.